# Remove/replace heartbleed vulnerability on 4.1.1 rooted?

Tags: root-access

I'm running stock TW 4.1.1 with root and xposed mods on a Galaxy note 2 with T-mo. Up to this point,  I've been happy with my setup, but now I'm reading that I am the only exception to the HB vulnerability on Android. I'd rather not upgrade, or flash a rom if I don't have to.  Is there a way I can replace the lib file in es file, or some other tactic? Where would the file be,  I can't find anything familiar in /system.lib. 
Am I understanding correctly that it is only vulnerable through browser, not apps? I changed all my passwords on app services that were susceptible. Trying to get a grasp on it all.
Edit 1:
I found Bluebox's heartbleed scanner in the Playstore via Android police.  It says I'm running 1.0.1c but heartbeat is disabled. It did report that Netflix app was running 1.0.1e and was enabled/vulnerable. PStouch, Google+, my VPN app and xbmc all have openssl too, but supposedly safe.

Comment: Only servers are affected by the vulnerability. You only need to update if you're using your phone as a web server, mail server, or some other kind of server using SSL.

Comment: Ok,  I just wish there was a way I could find out for sure what version of openssl I have on here,  without using that "lookout"scanner.  Not sure where to find it in es file. I've read the same thing about only being vulnerable If you're using device as server,  but then I've also read that it is an exposure through handshake on both ends.